# How to hover each cell for each day with react FullCalendar?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, mouseover, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

I have a [Reactjs FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) and I want when, I hover the cell of the days, the background will be blue also, the time of this cell will be appeared.

I try this :

```
.fc-widget-content td:hover {
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

But, I get :

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCKOq.gif

But, I want, to hover each cell for each day independently like this:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9FSh.gif

His code is:

```
<td onmouseover="highlightBG(this);" onmouseout="nohighlightBG(this);" style="color: transparent; height: 1.5em; text-align: right; padding-right: 2px; background-color: initial;"><span style="font-weight:900;">8:35</span></td>

function highlightBG(element) {                   
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#39b6f0';                   
        element.style.color = 'black';                 
}                  
function nohighlightBG(element) {                   
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; 
        element.style.color = 'transparent';                 
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You can't, because the cells are not individual HTML elements. It's an optical illusion caused by two separate HTML tables overlaid on top of each other. If you use your browser's element inspector you can start to see how it's done. So there's no single element for an individual "cell" which you can attach the hover rule onto. It's impossible.

Comment: But it's only a little bit of a minor enhancement to your GUI, so it shouldn't be a big deal if you can't do it. It doesn't affect any actual functionality.

Comment: @ADyson, but this https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9FSh.gif is developed with fullcalendar and jquery

Comment: Is it? Where did you get that from? Does it have source code?

Comment: `<td onmouseover="highlightBG(this);" onmouseout="nohighlightBG(this);" style="color: transparent; height: 1.5em; text-align: right; padding-right: 2px; background-color: initial;"><span style="font-weight:900;">8:35</span></td>`

Comment: `function highlightBG(element) {
                  element.style.backgroundColor = '#39b6f0';
                  element.style.color = 'black';
                }

                function nohighlightBG(element) {
                  element.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
                  element.style.color = 'transparent';
                }`

Comment: if you have code to share please use the "edit" button of your question to add it there, then it can be formatted properly. Code in comments is very hard to read, as you can hopefully see yourself.

Comment: Anyway, this code is simply generic code to highlight a `<td>`. You claimed "this is developed with fullCalendar and jQuery". But this code cannot work with fullCalendar to create what you see in that gif, because there is no single `<td>` which represents an individual cell. So again I ask...how was that gif generated? Is it the result of real HTML/CSS/JS code, or just from someone creating an animation themselves in a graphics program? As far as I know there is no way to reproduce that with code, because of the reasons I've already explained in my first comment.

Comment: (Well, actually you _could_ probably create it, but only by modifying the source code of the timegrid view in fullCalendar - fullCalendar knows where the "cells" are because it knows the co-ordinates where they will appear on the screen - so that when you select a slot, it knows what you selected. It does this based on positioning though, not on elements. So you couldn't do it with a simple CSS hover rule, you'd have to get more in-depth. You'd end up making a custom view based on timegrid. It won't be a simple task - probably not worth it for what you gain (as I hinted in my second comment)).

Comment: I use react fullcalendar, and probably it can be created because, fullcalendar have a select mirror whichcan selecting a grid

Comment: The fact you're using React is irrelevant, the underlying fullCalendar implementation is identical, the react part is just a connector between React and fullCalendar to make integration easier

Comment: Anyway, yes, it probably can be done - if you look at what selectMirror creates, or at the highlight the "select" functionality creates if you don't use the mirror, you'll see it creates an absolutely-positioned div over the relevant part of the grid. Like I said, fullCalendar internally knows the co-ordinates of the "cells". But they just co-ordinates, not HTML elements. And the API doesn't expose them to you. That's why it's possible, but you'd have to fork the fullCalendar source code to do it. And that's quite hard, so probably not worth bothering for this minor UI gain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222527/discussion-between-codelover-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `Jquery` and `Fullcalendar` like this:

```js
$(this).children("td").each(function () {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $(this).html('<div class="current-time">' + $(this).parent().parent().data("time").substring(0, 5) + "</div>")
    }, function () {
        $(this).html("")
    })
})
}
},
function () {
    $(this).children(".temp-cell").remove()
}): $(".fc-widget-content:not(.fc-axis)").hover(function () {
$(this).html() || ($(this).append('<td class="temp-cell" style="border: 0px; width:' + (Number($(".fc-day").width()) + 3) + 'px"></td>'), $(this).children("td").each(function () {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $(this).html('<div class="current-time">' + $(this).parent().parent().data("time").substring(0, 5) + "</div>")
    }, function () {
        $(this).html("")
    })
}))
}, function () {
$(this).children(".temp-cell").remove()
})
}
})
```

this will append `td` cells to the whole horizontal line and  you can simply have the time or hover any color you wish.